# I want to pass function in d3.json rather than .php file and want a ajax call to do that which can take pointer in the function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, d3.js

I have a d3 file to draw pie chart. In this file I pass "data.php" file in d3.json to fetch data from database. But I want to do this work in ajax call simply to fetch data from a function rather than data.php file. Please solve it, if it is possible.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.php",
    data: {get_param: 'value'},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var names = data
        $('#piechart').html(data);

        piechart();
    }

});
```

My functions is now in functions folder and i want to fetch data from it with an ajax call and do it by passing a pointer in the call.

Comment: You want to pass ajax to function right ? if that you want try   type: "POST",
    url: "data.php",
    data: {func: 'funcName', Pram},
    dataType: 'json

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please explain it in details.

Comment: type: "POST" because you will send some data to url: "data.php" then data will look for function with name funcName in data.php data: {func: 'funcName', Pram} and with success function(data) you will get the return data from this function

Comment: Does I need js validation file?

Comment: for what ? Ajax do not request validation